# curl the url onclick button

Tags: php, curl

i m trying to curl the url in my code to a page but curl is not working, i have tested it by

```
$url="http://merimobiles.com/cart.php?action=add&product_id=9949"
echo file_get_contents($url);
```

and it gives the not found error,
curl code is here

```
$ch = @curl_init();
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,$url);
$response = @curl_exec($ch);
@curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove @ from curl_init, curl_setopt, curl_exec and check error:

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if ($response === false) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
```

Comment: it shows the echo part Curl error: but does not return any error

Answer (score 0):

I saw what in this url

```
http://merimobiles.com/cart.php?action=add&product_id=9949
```

was redirect to

```
http://www.merimobiles.com/cart.php?suggest=51444ec01e7a2
```

You should set curl option

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

Comment: it takes it to the page but on that page an error is being shown
The requested URL /templates/__custom/lib/shipping_schedule/shipping-1-text.html was not found on this server.

Comment: yes, cause it's iframe. In this case i would parse the doc and add `http://www.merimobiles.com` before `/templates/__custom/lib/shipping_schedule/shipping-1-text.html`